# Vector space with new scalar multiplication defined over finite field still vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

If $V$ is a vector space (not the zero vector space) over $\mathbb{R}$, and if $F$ is a finite field.  how could I show that it is not possible to define a new scalar multiplication of $F$ on $V$, in a way that $V$ with this scalar multiplication and the usual addition becomes a vector space over $F$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $V$ is the zero vector space, it *is* possible.

Comment: Use the restrictive facts about cardinalities of vector spaces as constrained by the size of the base field.

Comment: But what if V is not the zero vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the characteristic of $F$ be $p$. Then:

$$\vec 0 = 0 \cdot \vec v = \underbrace{(1+1+1+\cdots+1)}_{p\text{ terms}} \vec v \ne \underbrace{\vec v + \vec v + \vec v + \cdots + \vec v}_{p\text{ terms}} = p\vec v$$